# Age at January 1st in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to know what formula to use in age calculation to get someone’s age at January the 1st 2018, after input of his date of birthday.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do have an age calculation in our [help content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/82/faq/age-calculations) that can be set up to display a users age based on their entered birthday.

1. Add a Date field to your form labelled Birth Date.
2. Add a Calculation field labelled Age, set to the Text type.
3. Insert the following expression as your calculation:

> =DateTime.Today.Year - BirthDate.Year + (if DateTime.Today.Month < BirthDate.Month or (DateTime.Today.Month = BirthDate.Month and 
>   DateTime.Today.Day < BirthDate.Day) then -1 else 0)

Comment: That would calculate the age acording to today date, but i really need it to calculate the age on january the 1st.

Comment: Late to the party on this one, but having stumbled onto this thread will looking for how to calculate age on a specific date, we just need to modify Nicholas' answer a bit to `=DateTime.Parse("31/7/2020").Year - BirthDate.Year + (if DateTime.Parse("31/7/2020").Month < BirthDate.Month or (DateTime.Parse("31/7/2020").Month = BirthDate.Month and DateTime.Parse("31/7/2020").Day < BirthDate.Day) then -1 else 0)` or to remove the hardcoded year `=DateTime.Today.Year - DateOfBirth.Year + (7 < DateOfBirth.Month or (7 = DateOfBirth.Month and 31 < DateOfBirth.Day) ? -1 : 0)`